# Reading SequenceFiles from S3 with PySpark on EMR causes RACK_LOCAL locality

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, sequencefile

I am trying to use PySpark on EMR to analyze some data stored as SequenceFiles on S3, but running into performance issues due to data locality. Here is a very simple sample that doesn't work well:

```
seqRDD = sc.sequenceFile("s3n://<access>:<secret>@<bucket>/<table>/day=2015-07-04/hour=*/*")
seqRDD.count()
```

The issue is with the `count` action, it works fine but distribution of the tasks is very poor. For some reason in the Spark logs I only see 2 IPs of the cluster doing any actual work while the rest sits idle. I tried with a 5 node cluster and 50 nodes cluster and it's always only 2 IPs appearing in the logs.

Also very strange is that these 2 IPs have a locality of RACK_LOCAL. I'm presuming it's because data is in S3 so it's not local, but how can I make Spark use the whole cluster instead of just 2 instances?

I didn't do anything specific for Spark configuration on EMR, simply installing it on EMR via native app and I believe it takes care automatically of optimizing the configs.

I saw this in the logs, the `allowLocal=false` could be an issue but I couldn't find anything on that:

```
15/07/17 23:55:27 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: count at :1
15/07/17 23:55:27 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (count at :1) with 1354 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
15/07/17 23:55:27 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 1(count at :1)
```

Some logs that follow when running the `count`, showing only 2 IPs:

```
15/07/17 23:55:28 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1354 missing tasks from Stage 1 (PythonRDD[3] at count at :1)
15/07/17 23:55:28 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Adding task set 1.0 with 1354 tasks
15/07/17 23:55:28 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, ip-172-31-41-210.ec2.internal, RACK_LOCAL, 1418 bytes)
15/07/17 23:55:28 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, ip-172-31-36-179.ec2.internal, RACK_LOCAL, 1420 bytes)
15/07/17 23:55:28 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on ip-172-31-36-179.ec2.internal:39998 (size: 3.7 KB, free: 535.0 MB)
15/07/17 23:55:28 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on ip-172-31-41-210.ec2.internal:36847 (size: 3.7 KB, free: 535.0 MB)
15/07/17 23:55:29 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on ip-172-31-41-210.ec2.internal:36847 (size: 18.8 KB, free: 535.0 MB)
15/07/17 23:55:31 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3, ip-172-31-41-210.ec2.internal, RACK_LOCAL, 1421 bytes)
15/07/17 23:55:31 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) in 3501 ms on ip-172-31-41-210.ec2.internal (1/1354)
15/07/17 23:55:31 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, ip-172-31-41-210.ec2.internal, RACK_LOCAL, 1420 bytes)
15/07/17 23:55:31 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3) in 99 ms on ip-172-31-41-210.ec2.internal (2/1354)
15/07/17 23:55:33 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5, ip-172-31-36-179.ec2.internal, RACK_LOCAL, 1420 bytes)
15/07/17 23:55:33 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) in 5190 ms on ip-172-31-36-179.ec2.internal (3/1354)
15/07/17 23:55:36 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6, ip-172-31-41-210.ec2.internal, RACK_LOCAL, 1420 bytes)
15/07/17 23:55:36 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4) in 4471 ms on ip-172-31-41-210.ec2.internal (4/1354)
15/07/17 23:55:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 6.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, ip-172-31-36-179.ec2.internal, RACK_LOCAL, 1420 bytes)
15/07/17 23:55:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 4.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5) in 3676 ms on ip-172-31-36-179.ec2.internal (5/1354)
15/07/17 23:55:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 7.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 8, ip-172-31-41-210.ec2.internal, RACK_LOCAL, 1420 bytes)
15/07/17 23:55:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 5.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6) in 3895 ms on ip-172-31-41-210.ec2.internal (6/1354)
15/07/17 23:55:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 8.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 9, ip-172-31-36-179.ec2.internal, RACK_LOCAL, 1420 bytes)
```

Comment: Also worth noting, I ran `pyspark` with `--master yarn-client`

Comment: Are you setting the number of executors?  By default with spark-submit it is 2.

Comment: @ChristopherB Oh, I was somehow under the impression that when setting up Spark on EMR it takes care of configuring the right number of executors in the config... I'll try setting up manually and see what happens, thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: This was because I didn't specify the `-x` option when installing Spark on EMR, so EMR doesn't configure anything for Spark if you don't specify that option somehow. The weird thing is that this option is not even indicated in their official doc ! But works perfectly after specifying it.